# What is the wrong with my verilog code?

Tags: verilog

i wanna write register file in `verilog` that is write and read data registers.
this is my code:

```
module registerfile(writeaddr1,writedata1,readaddr2,readdata2,readaddr3,readdata3,write,clock);
input [4:0] writeaddr1, readaddr2, readaddr3;
input [31:0] writedata1;
output[31:0]readdata2,readdata3;
reg [31:0]readdata2,readdata3;
input write,clock;
reg [31:0] cells [0:31];
always @(posedge clock) 
begin
if (write == 1) cells[writeaddr1] =writedata1;
   readdata2 = cells[readaddr2];
    readdata3 = cells[readaddr3];
end
endmodule
```

and this is my test bench.

```
module testreg;
  reg [3:0]addr1,addr2,addr3;
  reg [31:0]data1;
  reg write;
    wire [31:0]data2,data3;
reg clock ; //Rising edge every 10 timesteps
registerfile regf(addr1,data1,addr2,data2,addr3,data3,write,clock);
initial begin
  addr1=1;
  addr2=2;
  addr3=3;
  write=0;
  data1=32'bx;
  clock=0;
  #10
  addr1=1;
  addr2=1;
  addr3=3;
  write=1;
  data1=30;
  clock=1;
  #10
  $finish;
end
endmodule
```

but i don't know why `data2` between 10 and 20 is xxx? I am write 30 in that location:(

Comment: FYI, you should use non-blocking (`<=`) assignments to `cell` and `readdata*`

Answer (score 3):

If the period of clk is 20ns, Between 0ns and 20ns first write is applied, but `data2` is not the same `data1`, because read and write is simultaneous and when you write a value on memory, at the next clk rising edge you can read the same value from memory. Then between 20ns and 40ns (on clk rising edge) `data2` is equal to `data1`.

---

In the module `testreg` size of `addr1` should be `[4:0]` :

```
 reg [4:0] addr1,addr2,addr3;
```

---

As Greg said in the module `registerfile` it's better to use non-blocking assignments (`<=`) such as the following code :

```
always @(posedge clock) 
    if (write) begin
        cells[writeaddr1] <= writedata1;
        readdata2 <= cells[readaddr2];
        readdata3 <= cells[readaddr3];
    end
```

---

Just use the following code and continue to run simulation until 40ns :

```
initial begin
    addr1=1;
    data1=30;
    addr2=1;
    write=1;
end

initial begin
    clock = 0;
    forever #10 clock = ~clock;
end
```

I simulated your code with the above changes and could get the correct result.

Comment: you mean that after this line:"cells[writeaddr1] =writedata1;" , this line( readdata2 = cells[readaddr2];) doesn't execute?why? why it waits for another clk rising edge? @amir

Comment: i add this:"clock=0;
  write=0;
  addr2=1;
  addr3=4;
  addr1=6;
  data1=32'bx;
  #10
   clock=1;
  write=0;
  addr2=1;
  addr3=4;
  addr1=6;
  data1=32'bx;
  #10" to generate another posedge for clock ,but still data2 is xxxx @amir

Comment: also it is wrong in all of my test, wave of data2 and data3 is xxxx :( @amir

Comment: _"Actually in always blocks all of the parameters are assigned at the end of block simultaneous, then when you read a value, it is related to previous write."_ This is not correct. Non-blocking assignments (`<=`) are assigned at the end of all stimulus scheduled before NBA updates. Blocking (`=`) is an immediate assignment. The content of a procedural block is executed top-to-bottem; last assignment wins. By design different procedural blocks are allowed to execute in a non-determinate order at the mercy of the simulator.

Comment: @Greg Ok, Thank you. I edited my answer. I think the following link is very useful to learn more about block and non-block assignment. You forced me to read it ! [Nonblocking Assignments in Verilog Synthesis, Coding, Styles That Kill!](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf)

Comment: @ user4615534 : I simulated your code and get the correct result. I completed my answer with the final changes.

Comment: thank you @amir . is my question really bad question with -4 rate?

Comment: thank you too @Greg but if i want to read depends on write, i mean that in  posede of clock after writing some data, i can read it at next line. what is wrong with it?

Comment: Because of race conditions, it is recommended to avoid using blocking assignments (`=`) in `always` blocks that are written to generate sequential logic. If you want to read data asynchronously, you can use `assign` statements or `always` blocks that are written to generate combinational logic. For more information you can read the following link : [Nonblocking Assignments in Verilog Synthesis, Coding, Styles That Kill!](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf)